# Looking for sample lat/long data of thousands of US addresses

Tags: data-request, usa, geocoding, csv

In order to test some mapping and geocoding functionality, I'm looking for a free data source containing a few thousand US addresses, including latitude and longitude. I need them distributed among a number of states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some time on Google brought up this list of 8902 Starbucks around the US: http://www.gpspassion.com/forumsen/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=67416

Here it is as a gist: https://gist.github.com/dankohn/09e5446feb4a8faea24f

Comment: nicely done! you should add this dataset to our datahub.io repository http://datahub.io/organization/opendata-stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. It is HUD's dataset on inspection scores for multi-family dwellings providing subsidized housing. There are 20,000 addresses with lat/lon across the US.

https://www.huduser.gov/portal/datasets/pis.html

Look at:  Multifamily Physical Inspection Scores 2015

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I came across this OpenAddresses project: [OpenAddresses.io](http://openaddresses.io/).  Something like 215 million addresses available, broken down I believe by US state for the US ones.